# netCDF files has no variables in python when importing with xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray, satellite

I'm VERY new to xarray, and I tried to import a satellite netcdf files into python using xarray using this file: https://tropomi.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data//S5P_TROPOMI_Level2/S5P_L2__NO2____HiR.1/2020/003/S5P_OFFL_L2__NO2____20200103T170946_20200103T185116_11525_01_010302_20200105T100506.nc

This is the code I used:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tropomi = xr.open_dataset('test2.nc', engine = 'netcdf4')
tropomi
```

Output:
[image]

But the output does not present any variables, and has 53 attributes - why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: can you add the output?

Comment: I have added a screencap of the output.

Comment: How about the output of `nudump -h test2.nc`?

Comment: Where would I do that? In the terminal? When I did I got the message "Command Not Found"

Comment: You should type it in the terminal. `ncdump` is included in the netcdf4 distribution. Which command did you use to install xarray? by pip? or conda? I used conda to install it. My `ncdump` is in `${anaconda_path}/envs/${environment_name}/bin/ncdump`. I would like to see whether the output of `ncdump -h` and the one from `xarray` consistent each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. When you open the file without a group defined, you get the global attributes with no variables. You need to include a group='PRODUCT' to get the data products, like this:

```
tropomi = xr.open_dataset('test2.nc', group='PRODUCT')
```